# AccessDeniedException when calling the EKS Service with Administrator permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I'm trying to install EBS-CSI-Driver Add-on for EKS on AWS, but I have error with Denied status. Although my account have administratoraccess role. Why does this happen?

Via CLI:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateAddon operation: User: arn:aws:iam::my-user-id:user/my-user is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::my-user-id:role/EKS_NodeGroup_Role with an explicit deny"

Via Console:

> AccessDenied  namespaces "kube-system" is forbidden: User "eks:addon-manager" cannot patch resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system""

I added `AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy` into `EKS_NodeGroup_Role` but still have same error.

Comment: Search for IAM policy attached to your AdministratorAccess role that sets an explicit Deny for such operations. You can use AWS IAM Acess Analyzer to debug this. We can't help you w/o seeing your full IAM setup.

Comment: thank @VladHolubiev . after re-check in IAM policy, I found the problem.

Comment: but I have another error :"code": "AccessDenied",
                    "message": "namespaces \"kube-system\" is forbidden: User \"eks:addon-manager\" cannot patch resource \"namespaces\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kube-system\"". how I can check the permission need for addon-manager ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the same issue. Not sure why.

However, the issue cloud solved by adding “patch” in clusterrole “eks:addonmanager”.

Comment: you mean I have to add “eks:addonmanager” in allow action of cluster role ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is possibly missing eks:addon-cluster-admin clusterrolebinding.
It might be checked by:

$ kubectl get clusterrolebinding | grep addon
eks:addon-cluster-admin             ClusterRole/cluster-admin
eks:addon-manager                   ClusterRole/eks:addon-manager

If there is no addon-cluster-admin, it might be created by:

$ vi eks-addon-cluster-admin.yaml

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: eks:addon-cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: eks:addon-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

kubectl apply -f eks-addon-cluster-admin.yaml

Then, re-create the Amazon EBS CSI Driver, it should be in "Active" status.